# Fourier transform in $\mathbb{L}^2(\mathbb{R})\setminus\mathbb{L}^1(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, hilbert-spaces, fourier-transform

In a book I've found  the following definition for the Fourier transform in  $\mathbb{L}^2(\mathbb{R})\\$:

$g(k)$=$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\frac{d}{dk}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-ikx}-1}{-ix}f(x)dx\\$
Now I don't understand why this definition is equivalent to the usual one that is:
$g(k)=\lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-N}^{+N}e^{-ikx}f(x)dx\\$  where the limit is in the sense of the norm $||\cdot||_2$. Where can I find a proof of the equivalence of the two definitions?

Comment: What is the reference for the book in which you've found that definition? The two expressions are clearly equal over classes of "good" functions (like $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$). In order to prove the equality for every $L^2$-function you need to define in which sense the derivative $d/dk$ is taken.

Comment: I've  found  a reference for the first expression of g(k) in the following site: https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Plancherel_theorem

Comment: It appears also in the book "Trigonometric Series, Volume II, A.Zygmund, Cambridge  Mathematical Library", on page 249-250.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a proof, but a bit of unification of the two definitions.

Using the definition of derivative we have
$$
\frac{d}{dk} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-ikx}-1}{-ix} \, f(x) \, dx
= \lim_{\delta\to 0} \frac{1}{\delta} \left( \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-i(k+\delta)x}-1}{-ix} \, f(x) \, dx - \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-ikx}-1}{-ix} \, f(x) \, dx \right)
\\= \lim_{\delta\to 0} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-i(k+\delta)x}-e^{-ikx}}{-i\delta x} \, f(x) \, dx
= \lim_{\delta\to 0} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-i\delta x}-1}{-i\delta x} \,e^{-ikx} \, f(x) \, dx
\\= \lim_{N\to\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-ix/N}-1}{-ix/N} \,e^{-ikx} \, f(x) \, dx
.
$$

The other definition is
$$
\lim_{N\to\infty} \int_{-N}^{N} e^{-ikx} \, f(x) \, dx
= \lim_{N\to\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \chi_{[-N,N]}(x) \, e^{-ikx} \, f(x) \, dx
.
$$

Thus, both definitions are of the form
$$
\lim_{N\to\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} h_N(x) \, e^{-ikx} \, f(x) \, dx
,
$$
where $h_N \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and $h_N(x) \to 1$ pointwise (and on every compact set).

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
    \lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-R}^{R}\frac{e^{-ikx}-1}{-ix}f(x)dx
    &=\lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-R}^{R}\int_0^k e^{-isx}ds f(x)dx \\
    &=\lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}\int_0^k\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-R}^{R}e^{-isx}f(x)dx ds \\
    &=\int_0^k \hat{f}(s)ds
\end{align}